# Why are mermaids naked?

Tags: celtic, european-folklore, fairies, mermaids

In images from Roman to contemporary Britain, mermaids are usually not wearing any clothes. Other types of fairies, spirits, and gods are usually depicted at least partly dressed.
Why then are mermaids naked? Or aren't they?

Are mermaids naked in written sources like fairy tales and legends, too? And do they explain the nudity?

Comment: It may have something to do with the idea of [Sirens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siren_(mythology)) luring men to their doom. Although the sirens are winged, sailors were their targets.

Comment: The physical creature which led in part to the myth of mermaids is the manatee, which traditionally doesn't wear clothing.

Answer (score 3):

A number of reasons: mermaids are part of nature, not culture, [Classical depictions](http://www.theoi.com/Pontios/Amphitrite.html) of marine deities and other spirits show them naked, and because mermaids are supposed to be sexy.

[image]